# traversing a 2-dimensional array in java

Tags: java

i watch in a tutorial that i can traverse an array of object in this way:

```
     Animals[] an = new Animals[2];

         for (Animals a:an){
                 .
                 .
         }
```

But now i want to traverse a 2 dimensional array and when i use this code i have a problem(says:incompatible types
              required:appl1.Animals
              foundLappl1.Animals[]). when i use this code

```
   Animals[][] an = new Animals[2][2];

      for (Animals a:an){
             .
             .
       }
```

Does anyone knows how can i overcome this problems. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use *nested* loops, as follows:

```
Animals[][] an = new Animals[2][2];

for (Animals[] inner : an) {
    for (Animals a : inner) {
        // Execute code on "Animals" object a
    }
}
```

---

**Why does this work?**

Look at your first example (reposted here for convenience):

```
Animals[] an = new Animals[2];

for (Animals a : an) {
    // Do stuff here.
}
```

This works because `an` is an array of `Animals` objects.  The `for` loop iterates through each `Animals` object, performing some action on them one-by-one.

Now look at my answer posted above (again, reposted here for context):

```
Animals[][] an = new Animals[2][2];

for (Animals[] inner : an) {
    for (Animals a : inner) {
        // Execute code on "Animals" object a
    }
}
```

This works because `an` is an array of **`Animals[]`** objects. The first `for` loop iterates through each **`Animals[]`**.  At that point, you have an array of Animals objects, so you can use the same solution as above: a single `for` loop to iterate through each of the `Animals` object and perform some action on them one-by-one.

Answer (score 4):

A two-dimensional array is really an array of arrays. You need nested loops: the outer loop goes through the array of arrays, and the inner loop goes through the elements of each individual array.

```
Animals[][] ann = new Animals[2][2];

for (Animals[] an:ann){
    for (Animals a:an){
         .
         .
    }
}
```

Comment: This is correct.  You can't do this with a single loop...not without difficulty.